# Sql date between query with a date and number of days

Tags: php, mysql, date, cakephp

I have a table called Renewals as follows

```
id | item_name | next_renewal_date | alert_before_days
2  | Test      | 2015-05-25        |  5
6  | Test4     | 2015-05-12        |  2
7  | Test7     | 2015-05-30        |  12
```

I would like to read the table by alert_before_days. For example, i need the rows with upcoming renewals by its alert_before_days from current date onwards.

I'm using cakephp and tried the following, but nothing works. it only selects the date as 1970-01-01

```
'conditions'=>array('Renewal.NextRenewalDate <=' =>  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+Renewal.AlertBeforeDays days"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime` will not recognize that expression. Do it with `mysql` -

```
'conditions'=>array(
     'Renewal.NextRenewalDate <=' => 'DATE_ADD(NOW() + INTERVAL `Renewal`.`NextRenewalDate` DAY)'
)
```

Comment: Some parse errors are there, could you please help me to find out?? The problem might be within DATE_ADD(NOW() + INTERVAL `Renewal`.`NextRenewalDate` DAY. May be with the quotes

Comment: My mistake. Missed the `'`s .. Updated the answer.

Comment: Oops.. It selects all entries from table.. How it is possible??